# Video Editor able to synchronize multiple video and audio tracks for Linux

Tags: linux, video, video-editing, audio-editing

I looking for a video-editing software which is able to load multiple video and audio files, and synchronize these tracks based on the audio data, so the audio tracks match exactly to the video tracks.

In my use cases I record an event by using multiple cameras (4, in my recent case) and a single high-quality microphone. Instead of doing this by hand, it is possible to do this in an automated way using popular programs which are available for the other two OS.

Most video-editors are quite basic and many of them support only one track at all. Cinelerra makes a quite professional impression but I couldn't find any informations about such a function.
The latter is also true for OpenShot, flowblade and Kdenlive.

Pitivi has fund-raising campaign, [listing a bpm detector](http://fundraiser.pitivi.org/#collapseTwo) as top-wanted feature allowing automatic editing.

Comment: See also, basically the same question (syncing multiple recordings based on audio) on http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14529/sync-separate-audio-to-videobad-camera-audio-free-nle-recommendations.

Answer (score 6):

Kdenlive can synchronize videos using a audio reference. Select the track you want to use as the audio reference, press the right mouse button, and select `Set Audio Reference`. Then select the track you want to aligned to the reference, press the right mouse button and select `Align Audio to Reference`.

Comment: Thanks, it's true :) As far as I understood the feature, how it is [documented](https://userbase.kde.org/Kdenlive/Manual/Timeline/Right_Click_Menu), the feature does not work on tracks, but on clips.

Comment: Also, kdenlive's align to reference can't handle the case where the samplerate clocks of the two audio recorders don't match, requiring one track to be stretched to match the other.  It only fits a one-parameter shift model, not a 2-parameter shift + stretch model.

Comment: If your clocks are all the same speed, though, you could find the needed offsets using kdenlive, and then use those offsets in something that does support multiple video tracks, right?